# Add a user defined language to notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have Juniper_JunOS.xml file and I want to add this language to notepad++ languages. How can I do this?
I am using windows vista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you found that XML from the [official list](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=User_Defined_Language_Files#J) of User Defined Languages.

If you scroll down at that page, you will notice that there's a `How to install user defined language files` section, where it states: *To add syntax colouring from one of these, the simplest way is to open the User Defined Language panel, click "Import" and navigate to the desired file.*

So, in Notepad++ v6.5.1. (latest version), go to menu `Language` > `Define your language...` and then press `Import` button and select your XML file.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I wanted to add "pspscript" to Python language in Notepad++. I solved the problem thus:

1. Go to the directory where Notepad++ resides:

   - C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++
2. Open "langs.xml"
3. Search for the language that has the same or similar syntax to your language.

   - in my case, "Python".
4. It looks like this:
   <Language name="python" ext="py pyw" commentLine="#" tabSettings="132">
   <Keywords name, etc. etc.
5. Add your extension to the list:... ext="py pyw" ...

   - In my case "pspscript":
6. ext="py pyw pspscript"
7. Restart Notepad++
8. Open any file with the extension of your language. In my case "*.pspscript" and it will have the same highlighting and format as your chosen language (In my case Python). It's not exactly what you wanted, but I hope that I have given you an idea along similar lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good list of User Defined Language (UDL) files: [github.com/notepad-plus-plus/userDefinedLanguages/blob/master/udl-list.md](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/userDefinedLanguages/blob/master/udl-list.md)

Note that if you have backup/cloud options set in settings, your userDefineLang.xml file will not be here: **%AppData%\Notepad++\userDefineLang.xml**. It will in the backup/cloud folder you set.

This is another important distinction. UDL files can be saved in a *folder* (**%Appdata%\Notepad++\userDefineLangs**) or multiple languages can be saved in a single *file* (**%AppData%\Notepad++\userDefineLang.xml**). Or, if Notepad++ was a portable install, in the portable folder (for the file option, like this: **<notepad++_directory>\userDefineLange.xml**).

So, you can add a new UDL by importing the xml file from the User Defined Language window (Language > User Defined Language > Define your language > Import button) , putting the file in the proper folder, or pasting the UserLang code directly into the userDefineLang.xml file.

Also, you can of course manually create a user defined language through the User Defined Language window.

Source: [npp-user-manual.org/docs/user-defined-language-system/](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/user-defined-language-system/)